What is the correct way to run a custom runtime on AWS Lambda
I am currently trying to execute Haskell code as an AWS Lambda function to test how well it runs. I am not totally familiar with docker and less familiar with AWS. I have been trying to follow a few guides for deploying Haskell as a custom runtime specifically, however I'm not super proficient and they seem to be outdated in places.
My question is, am I approaching this correctly for running Haskell performance experiments on AWS? I have seen a video from AWS on youtube that shows a user executing powershell (.ps1) files by using a runtime layer and changing the handler in the function settings. I want to test how Haskell is performing on AWS when it is as close to a native AWS runtime as I can make it without doing a bunch of hacking. I wont be running a lot of complex code I can happily contain all my logic within a function and upload runtimes built in docker containers if I need to. Are there approaches to this task that I am not exploring?
I have attached my current multistage docker file that I am using to build a hello world Haskell file and then zip it to "function.zip" for uploading to AWS Lambda. I had issues with zipping on windows and uploading so I decided to use the same amazonlinux 2023 runtime as I will be using when creating a function in AWS. I had attempted to setup stack and cabal in the dockerfile but ran into issues and instead opted to just build from the latest Haskell and build the code that I copied into the image.
The lambda function technically fails and appears to run twice but I can see that it is printing my "Hello, Haskell!" message when I run test. Within my docker container I zip my haskell build and bootstrap file for uploading to AWS.
RESULT OF RUNNING TEST IN AWS LAMBDA UI
Test Event Name: helloWorld

Response:
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
    "errorMessage": "RequestId: ... Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason"
}

Function Logs:
Running bootstrap script...
Found Haskell binary, executing...
Hello, Haskell!
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 31.97 ms Phase: init Status: error Error Type: Runtime.ExitError

Running bootstrap script...
Found Haskell binary, executing...
Hello, Haskell!
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 179.92 ms Phase: invoke Status: error Error Type: Runtime.ExitError

START RequestId: ... Version: $LATEST
RequestId: ... Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason Runtime.ExitError
END RequestId: ...
REPORT RequestId: ... Duration: 181.62 ms Billed Duration: 182 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 4 MB


DOCKERFILE
FROM haskell:latest as build

RUN mkdir -p /aws_lambda_runtime_wjs
WORKDIR /aws_lambda_runtime_wjs

COPY . .

RUN stack setup && \
    stack build --install-ghc --copy-bins

RUN BINARY_PATH=$(stack path --local-install-root)/bin/aws-lambda-runtime && \
    echo "Binary located at: $BINARY_PATH" && \
    cp $BINARY_PATH /aws_lambda_runtime_wjs/aws-lambda-runtime-wjs

FROM amazonlinux:2023

RUN yum -y update && \
    yum -y install zlib gmp ncurses-libs xz zip

RUN mkdir -p /var/task

COPY --from=build /aws_lambda_runtime_wjs/aws-lambda-runtime-wjs /var/task/aws-lambda-runtime-wjs

COPY --from=build /aws_lambda_runtime_wjs/bootstrap /var/task/bootstrap

RUN chmod +x /var/task/bootstrap

RUN chmod +x /var/task/aws-lambda-runtime-wjs

WORKDIR /var/task

RUN zip -r9 function.zip bootstrap aws-lambda-runtime-wjs

ENTRYPOINT ["/var/task/bootstrap"]


BOOTSTRAP
#!/bin/sh

# Debugging information
echo "Running bootstrap script..."

# Ensure the Haskell binary exists before running
if [ -f /var/task/aws-lambda-runtime-wjs ]; then
    echo "Found Haskell binary, executing..."
    # Execute the Haskell binary
    exec /var/task/aws-lambda-runtime-wjs
else
    echo "Haskell binary not found!"
    exit 1
fi

HASKELL CODE COPIED TO DOCKER CONTAINER
module Main where

-- A simple main function that prints a string
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello, Haskell!"


did you try googling "ghc aws lambda" seems there's a lot that goes into it. but did you consider that cold start times are probably going to be terrible? might be fine for long-running tasks though...

The reason your lambda is running twice is because you're not supplying the correct execution response, so the supporting infrastructure doesn't know whether the lambda has errored or succeeded. Have a look at the response/error section in the custom runtime docs here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html#runtimes-custom-response-streaming
There's also an example here on how you might want to call the response endpoint:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-walkthrough.html
